# Clarification regarding need for fixed address in context of constexpr pointers and references

Tags: c++, c++11

In Primer (while studying `constexpr`) I found that:

> variables defined inside a function
>   ordinarily are not stored at a fixed address. Hence, we cannot use a **constexpr**
>   pointer to point to such variables

1. Is it valid for all the values calculated at compile time or is it just a constraint for using keyword *constexpr*?
2. Does `const` keyword not ensures that the object would be determined (evaluated its value) at compile time despite being initialised by a literal?
3. Why define some reference with `constexpr` keyword:

   ```
         int i=9;   //Declared as global variable
         constexpr int &ref=i;
   ```

since `constexpr` implies top-level `const`ness which means the `ref` would be constant (which was true even when `constexpr` wasn't used as we can't refer to any other variable) and it fails to deliver the something which `const` reference does?

Comment: const doesn't guarantee much at all (since there is `const_cast`)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few misconceptions.

`constexpr` values are pretty much the only ones that behave like compile-time constants. So in q1 you're making a distinction that does not exist. You can store any address in a regular `const` pointer i.e. `T* const` .

Q2 is pretty much the same misconception. You can store a user's input in a `const std:: string`. That only means you can't change the string later.

Q3 is just a case of the language not trying to ban unnecessary things. There are a million other redundant things you can do.